# Django 3 when sending a letter to mail, images in the letter are not displayed, how to fix it?

Tags: django

```
subject = name_cinema
html_message = render_to_string('app_template/mail_template.html', context)
plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
from_email = 'From <example12090@gmail.com>'
to = email

mail.send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [to], html_message=html_message)
```

Layout mail_template.html, the problem is iz from the image, iz from the content of all the norms
it is shown less than 4 varianti, there, de invoking the power of the image. {% load static%} connection

```
<img src="{% static 'img/1234.png' %}" alt="1">
<img src="{% static 'img/1.png' %}" alt="2">
<img src="../../1234.png" alt="3">  

4<img src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/579eb482a8540ee55b0bf3db8695a783.jpg" alt="4">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiAV5.png)

Comment: Static will not work in your email, since that leads to `/static/img/1234.png`, but it needs the protocol and host in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this does not work is because `{% static 'img/1234.png' %}` will be resolved to `/static/img/1234.png` or something similar. But there is no hostname or protocol, so the email client does not know where to fetch these images.

You can pass the site name, for example with:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

site_name = get_current_site(request).name
html_message = render_to_string(
    'app_template/mail_template.html',
    {'site_name': site_name, **context}
)
```

in the template, you can render these with:

```
<img src="{{ site_name }}{% static 'img/1234.png' %}" alt="1">
<img src="{{ site_name }}{% static 'img/1.png' %}" alt="2">
```

Comment: It is very useful to find out, but I still can’t fix the error, I’m on the local server, how can I fix it? Or do need to deploy a project on a hosting?

Comment: @alter_table: if it runs locally, you likely should also specify the port (so `:8000` for example), and also check if the email client allows this. You might want to check the "source code" in the email that has been send.